# Incorrect Number of Bindings Using a For Loop and Lists (Python & SQLite3)

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, for-loop, sqlite

I have a SQLite3 database that I am trying to update with a series of lists. I want each list element to input as a new row in the specified column. I am getting the following error:

> Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 9, and there are 10 supplied.

This doesn't make sense to me as I'm only supplying 9 lists as values. Some lists have 10 items and others have null entries, but they are all 10 elements long. I'm guessing that's where it's getting the 10 bindings from but I have no idea how to fix this.

I have 9 lists

```
Column1 = internetMessageIdList
Column2 = receivedDateTime,
etc.
etc...
```

For loop code:

```
for i in range(len(senderNameList)):
   c.execute("INSERT INTO tutorial_message (MessageID, MessageDate, MessageRecipientAddress, MessageRecipientName, MessageSubject, MessageCC, MessageBCC, MessageSenderAddress, MessageSenderName) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", (Column1[i], Column2[i], Column3,[i], Column4[i], Column5[i], Column6[i], Column7[i], Column8[i], Column9[i]))
```

Comment: Seems to me you are calling `c.execute(c.execute(query))` instead of just `c.execute(query)`. Maybe remove one of those `c.execute` calls?

Comment: Here's your problem: `Column3,[i]` - the misplaced comma means that you are indeed passing 10 items, rather than the 9 that you intended to. Also make sure you fix the issue noted by @CharlieWindolf above.

Comment: what is (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) ? is there a that kinda string formatting?

Comment: Thanks guys! That extra c.execute statement is not actually in my code, must have accidentally added it, but that sneaky extra comma! Didn't notice that... now I'm just getting another error.. D: - "Error binding parameter 7 - probably unsupported type."